# How to create a random list with only unique values?

Tags: python, list, random

I want to create a random list with 100 elements. So far, so good...

**Example 1:** works fine, because the function has a range which is big enough not to repeat any value

```
list = random.sample(range(1,200),100)
```

**Example 2:** Does not work, because the range is too small (sample is larger than population)

```
list = random.sample(range(50,80),100)
```

I am looking for a way to create that random list with more values than the range and it is no problem that the elements exists several times.

Comment: For Python 3.6 or later: `random.choices(range(50, 80), k=100)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, do not use `random.sample`, but build the list from elements chosen within a range:

```
import random

[random.randrange(50, 80) for _ in range(100)]
```

#### example output:

```
[57,
 52,
 59,
 67,
 52,    # some elements repeat
 64,
 75,
...
```

Comment: That works fine. Thank you for the fast answer !

Comment: Thx for the hind, but be able to accept the answer nees a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

Use [numpy random](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#numpy.random.randint):

```
import numpy as np
np.random.randint(low=3,high=12,size=100)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [numpy.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

```
import numpy as np
l = range(50,80)
np.random.choice(l, 100, True)
```

Comment: This solution ist nice, too! But it creates a ndarray.... But it is easy to convert to a list. Reblochon Masque 's solution is more compact.

Answer (score 0):

Use `list comprehension` + `randint`,

```
[random.randint(1,200) for _ in range(100)]
```

See the element are repeating the count is not `100`,

```
In [6]: len(set([random.randint(1,200) for _ in range(100)]))
Out[6]: 76
```